# Need a regular expression pattern similar to xcode quickly open file dialog

Tags: regex, xcode

In xcode there is a "open quickly" file dialog which allows you to enter parts of the file name and it will appear as a result. For example if a file named: "mynewfile", I can enter a search term as: "myfi" (notice it's without spaces) and xode would show the result "mynewfile" while highlighting only the "my" and "fi" parts. I'm looking for the regular expression used to accomplish such effect but with a difference: it should match only the beginning of words:

if "my new file" is the name and "my file" is the search term the match will be for "my" and "file" only (it should return the indexes for the highlighting function I've written)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `autocomplete`

Comment: I'm using iOS 5, but I don't think that's important for the solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of regex Xcode search uses, but matching at the start of words is normally done by using a word boundary `\b`. So in your case, you might search for `\bmyfi`

Comment: It won't work for the following case: "my new file" is the name and "my file" is the search term, it will not match the "file" at the end. As I wrote this I think I found a solution: By splitting the search term into words and iterating through each one while using the word boundary

Comment: Yeah, the last part of what you said sounds about right. Note that the new search term would require an entirely different expression. Something more like this i guess (off the top of my head) `my\s\w+\sfile`